# JSoup in Android activity throws exception

Tags: android, jsoup

I’m currently using JSoup as external jar and the following snippet throws runtime exception in emulator and eventually app crashes:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(“http://www.cnn.com”).get();
06-18 14:00:17.272: I/dalvikvm(424): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.pamir.ODeskActivity.getList
06-18 14:00:17.272: W/dalvikvm(424): VFY: unable to resolve static method 25: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
06-18 14:00:17.282: D/dalvikvm(424): VFY: replacing opcode 0×71 at 0×0007
06-18 14:00:17.892: D/AndroidRuntime(424): Shutting down VM
06-18 14:00:17.905: W/dalvikvm(424): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0×40014760)
06-18 14:00:17.912: E/AndroidRuntime(424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 14:00:17.912: E/AndroidRuntime(424): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
06-18 14:00:17.912: E/AndroidRuntime(424): at com.pamir.ODeskActivity.getList(ODeskActivity.java:24)
```

Here is the manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ODeskActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Surely you'll want the INTERNET permission also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend what forgivengod said.

Also.

1. Right click Project
2. Click Android Tools
3. Click Fix Project Properties

And.

1. Click Project
2. Clean

Answer (score 2):

Make certain your JSoup jar file is exported along with the rest of your code.

1. Right click Project
2. Java Build Path
3. Order and Export
4. Check the box next your Jsoup jar entry.

Then reload the app onto your emulator or device.