# Calling Jsoup.connect crashes the android app

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, jsoup, runnable

I'm working on a location based app which detects the user's location and pulls the data based on the location from a website.
I am able to create an app to get user location successfully and I can even create an app to pull & parse HTML data using Jsoup. Now I tried to combine both but the app crashes.

I've read from other posts that creating a new thread for the HTTP requests will solve the issue but i'm unable to understand where to create it in the program and start the thread.

I tried creating a thread in the onCreate function and starting it in the LocationListener like this but still doesn't seem to work.

**onCreate**

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {  
    @Override
    public void run() { 
        Document doc;  
        try {                                              
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://google.com/").get();
            String title = doc.title();                    
            tv.setText(title);                       
        }
          catch (IOException e)
            {                          
                e.printStackTrace();                           
             }
    }

};
```

**LocationListener**

```
Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
    mythread.start();
```

**Here is the structure of my code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // some content
    }

  public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
  {

  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
  {       


       try { 
             // block of code to get user location
            }

       catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
}
```

I would like to keep this runnable thread in a separate function so that it is called only when there is a location change.

Can I get some help for this?
Thanks in advance

**update**  - Logcat

```
06-17 17:05:37.027: I/dalvikvm(14034): Could not find method org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect, referenced from method com.example.loc_update.MainActivity$1.run
06-17 17:05:37.027: W/dalvikvm(14034): VFY: unable to resolve static method 8726: Lorg/jsoup/Jsoup;.connect (Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/jsoup/Connection;
06-17 17:05:37.027: D/dalvikvm(14034): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
06-17 17:05:37.062: W/dalvikvm(14034): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419002a0)
06-17 17:05:37.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14034): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-11600
06-17 17:05:37.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14034): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup
06-17 17:05:37.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14034):    at com.example.loc_update.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:112)
06-17 17:05:37.062: E/AndroidRuntime(14034):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-17 17:05:37.282: D/libEGL(14034): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
06-17 17:05:37.307: D/libEGL(14034): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
06-17 17:05:37.312: D/libEGL(14034): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
06-17 17:05:37.312: D/(14034): Device driver API match
06-17 17:05:37.312: D/(14034): Device driver API version: 10
06-17 17:05:37.312: D/(14034): User space API version: 10 
06-17 17:05:37.312: D/(14034): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
06-17 17:05:37.372: D/OpenGLRenderer(14034): Enabling debug mode 0
06-17 17:05:46.847: I/Choreographer(14034): Skipped 566 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-17 17:05:48.527: I/Process(14034): Sending signal. PID: 14034 SIG: 9
```

Comment: If you could post the stack trace that would be helpful

Comment: Did you update for permissions? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Yes, all the necessary permissions have been added

Comment: There is a line which says "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."  If i can't place the runnable on onCreate, then where exactly do I use it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085162/jsoup-in-android-activity-throws-exception

That seems to be your exact error and solution

Comment: Fixing project properties didn't work out for me. All I wanted to know is where in this program should I be using the Runnable Thread function. The runnable thread here gets http content using Jsoup.

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to make any http requests. I recommend it because you get more control over it. ANd check out the example here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html about the jsoup and revert back if this method fails again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Jsoup in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651438/use-jsoup-in-android)